# How to mimic the reception of a message?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am using botbuilder for Node.js to build a chatbot (Zoe).

The issue I am facing now is that i want to mimic the reception of a message.

The use case is:

1. The client speaks in english
2. Zoe speaks in english with him
3. The client send a message in french outside a dialog
4. Before handling the message (use LUIS to recognize intent), Zoe asks the client if he wants him to speak in french with him or not
5. If yes, Zoe starts chatting in french. If not, she keeps chatting in english

After handling the change of the language, I want to handle the message in step 3 (use LUIS to recognize intent)

Is it possible?

Comment: Question is not clear? Who is client? Who is Zoe? What does the bot want to do here? How is the heading related to the question asked?

Comment: What do you mean by sending a message outside dialog in step 3?

Comment: @MasterChief, client is the person talking to the chatbot. Zoe is the chatbot.
I store the client message in the session, but I want to use the message later to know the user intent. I don't know if it is possible to recognize an intent from an utterance in code.

Comment: @AndriyKozachuk, messages exchanged inside a dialog are not forwarded to LUIS. Outside dialogs, messages are sent to LUIS to know the client intent, then start the corresponding dialog

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can check out the documentation on how to [Translate User Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-translation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs), which shows you how to implement the Microsoft Text Translation service in your bot.

You will need a Microsoft Text Translator API Key, which you can get from going to your [Azure portal](http://ms.portal.azure.com) > **Create a resource** (top-left + sign) > Search marketplace for "**Translator Text**" > **Create** on the blade that appears when you click Translator Text service

If you want more information on how to add more customizations after following the bot tutorial in the 1st link, you can check out the [Microsoft Text Translator documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/) for more details.

Comment: You're not answering my question. I am already translating user input.I am happy it going to be a built in functionality in v4. I am using v3 at the moment.

Comment: If you look at botbuilder unit tests, you'll find they user [processMessage](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.consoleconnector.html#processmessage) to mimic the reception of the mesage. I want to achieve the same behavior without using ConsoleConnector

Comment: So...to clarify, as it is a bit unclear as to what you are trying to do. Do you want to just be able to have LUIS "later on" be able to detect the intent from a message that you've stored?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve this behavior

Comment: I see. So you can do 1.) Use Microsoft Text Translator to both detect user's language, prompt the user if they want to switch to French or not with use of customization, and then translate text back to user in appropriate language 2.) you can make an API call to the LUIS endpoint in your customized method that detects that user selected French. Docs on how to make call to LUIS endpoint here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-node-get-intent